# ServerManagedPolicy issues

Tags: android, android-lvl

I have put in place the ServerManagedPolicy and am noticing some strange things.
(I have yet to publish the update)

So on a phone that has already purchased my application I have installed the new APK.
It all works good, however I then wanted to attempt testing when out of signal etc.
So I turn airplane mode on, and I instantly get the not licenced messaged.

The other account is not in my test account list.
Is this happening because I have not published the application so the VT,GT & GR results that are coming back are tiny or have I done something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may have something to do with this, need to roll back the version number for my testing !

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b83cc702603b0ee3?pli=1